# How to use a parameter column name value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I have an issue where we need to calculate some variable on the basis of different start and end date which can change as per the client.

Currently, I have implemented this solution as below. For example:

Created a static table : ref_table
Columns : training_start_date, training_end_date
Values : ISB_START_DT and ISB_END_DT
i.e. 1 row.
This table is created so if another client wants to use another dates,
values can be changed to
values : CS_START_DT and CS_END_DT
or anything.
Note: This table contain only 1 row at a time.
Query used:

```
   create table ref_table(training_start_date varchar(30), training_end_date 
   varchar(30); 
   insert into ref_table values('ISB_START_DT','ISB_END_DT')
```

Now, there is a another SQL query where we use this table and calculate features using that, there are a lot of columns and features being used in that query as well but I am giving a sample code.

```
Sample Code:

   Create or replace view prm_vw as  
   select s2.*,
          case 
          when NewValue < 0 then null
          else NewValue end as NewValue1
         from (
               select 
                     s1.*,
                     case 
                         when training_start_date  = 'ISB_START_DT' and 
                         training_start_date = 'ISB_END_DT' 
                         then ISB_START_DT - ISB_END_DT 
                         when training_start_date  = 'CS_START_DT' and 
                         training_start_date = 'CS_END_DT' 
                         then CS_START_DT - CS_END_DT 
                     end as NewValue
                from (
                     select 
                     AVG(date_to_calculate) OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS 
                     ISB_START_DT, 
                     AVG(date_to_calculate) OVER (PARTITION BY REGION) AS 
                     CS_START_DT,
                     ISB_END_DT,
                     CS_END_DT
                     ref.*
                     from prm_cmop
                     cross join 
                     ref_table ref
                 )s1
            )s2
```

I have implemented this in the above way but I feel this is not the optimized way as I am still hard coding and checking if training_start_date = 'ISB_START_DT' as I can't directly right the code as ISB_START_DT - ISB_END_DT As NewValue as training_start_date - training_end_date because training_start_date contains column name ISB_START_DT and I am interested in the column value of ISB_START_DT. Also, if in future client wants us to use another column, then i have to change my view script again to include that in case when lines.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please format your question properly. It is unreadable this way. Also, please include the definitions for all relevant tables. Are you trying to define a PLPGSQL function with column names as parameters?

Comment: I have tried to explain it, does that help?

Comment: Show us the sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, no. `ISB_START_DT` and friends are strings, not dates. SQL knows nothing about subtraction of strings. You have to place actual dates (OK, strings that can be parsed as dates) in your table. Maybe `ISB_START_DT` is a variable in your application language, you have to expand it _before_ passing the query to SQL, SQL won't expand it for you. And in your SQL code, use the _column name_ instead.

Comment: yes dario, thats y needed suggestion on the best approach to implement this. And ISB_START_DATE is calculated in the view...and used on the upper query to calculate newvalue as per the reference table...thnks for suggestion..